# Avoiding vtable pointer overhead in array of known type

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, vtable

This is gonna be a long one, but bear with me.

Let's say I'm writing a program that deals with animals

```
struct animal {
    virtual ~animal() {
    }

    virtual std::string get_noise() const = 0;
};

struct dog : public animal {
    std::string get_noise() const override {
        return "Woof";
    }
};

struct cat : public animal {
    std::string get_noise() const override {
        return "Meow";
    }
};
```

The `animal` base class is useful because now we can write a function that works for any type of `animal`.

```
void make_noise(const animal& target) {
    std::cout << target.get_noise() << std::endl;
}
```

We can also make a factory function that returns the right animal when given its type.

```
std::unique_ptr<animal> make_animal(const std::string& type) {
    if (type == "dog") {
        return std::unique_ptr<animal>(new dog);
    } else {
        return std::unique_ptr<animal>(new cat);
    }
}
```

Let's instantiate some animals to check that everything works as expected.

```
dog puppy;
make_noise(puppy);

std::unique_ptr<animal> kitty = make_animal("cat");
make_noise(*kitty);
```

Great. I love cats. So much, in fact, that I need an array of 10 billion of them.

```
std::vector<cat> cats(10000000000);
make_noise(cats[0]);
```

But oh no! Our program throws an exception now. Because of the vtable pointer, the `cat` class is 8 bytes in size and storing 10 billion kittens would require 80 gigabytes of memory. Sad!

I won't give up yet though, there is a solution! Let's start by removing the `animal` base class from both of the derived classes.

```
struct dog {
    std::string get_noise() const {
        return "Woof";
    }
};

struct cat {
    std::string get_noise() const {
        return "Meow";
    }
};
```

Now the challenge is, how do we implement the `make_noise` and `make_animal` functions? We could write a generic `make_noise` function but the type of its parameters won't always be known at compile time. We need some type to represent a dynamic animal instance but since polymorphism through inheritance turned out to be no good, we'll have to improvise.

Taking inspiration from fat pointers in rust, let's manually implement a vtable!

```
struct animal_vtable {
    std::string (*get_noise)(const void*);
};

template<class T>
static std::string get_noise(const void* ptr) {
    return static_cast<const T*>(ptr)->get_noise();
}

struct animal {
    const void* value;
    const animal_vtable* vtable;

    template<class T>
    animal(const T& value) {
        static animal_vtable vtable = {
            ::get_noise<T>,
        };

        this->value = &value;
        this->vtable = &vtable;
    }

    std::string get_noise() const {
        return vtable->get_noise(value);
    }
};
```

Let's ignore for a moment that this now only works for `const` animals, and also that we'll need another class that is basically identical to `animal` except using a non-const animal pointer if we want it to work for those as well.

At least now we can implement our `make_noise` function again.

```
void make_noise(animal target) {
    std::cout << target.get_noise() << std::endl;
}
```

That doesn't look too bad, and now it works for 10 billion cats with only 10 gigabytes of memory.

```
dog puppy;
make_noise(puppy);

std::vector<cat> cats(10000000000);
make_noise(cats[0]);
```

But we have another problem, implementing `make_animal`. We can't simply return a `std::unique_ptr<animal>` because the `animal::value` pointer wouldn't get properly destroyed. We'd have to add a destructor to our vtable and have yet another class that is basically identical to `animal` except with a destructor that calls the destructor from our vtable.

At this point the code is becoming unwieldy. I am not satisfied with how poorly the custom "fat" pointer works with standard library types such as `std::unique_ptr`. And with the manual vtables it almost feels like we're programming in C again.

So finally, for my question, is there a better way? I don't mind writing some boilerplate template metaprogramming magic if that helps keep the rest of my code clean.

C++ is said to be a language where you "don't pay for what you don't use", and yet I'm having to pay for storing the vtable 10 billion times in my `cats` array even though I know at compile time that the vtable will always be that of a cat, or risk turning my code into an unreadable mess.

Thank you for making it to the end.

I'm going to bed now.

Comment: AFAIK the vtable is stored once per _class_ so it should only exist once

Comment: @MVirts I think you misunderstood, my question is about the vtable pointer that is stored in every instance, I've updated the title to clarify this. @user4581301 I'm still left with the problem of implementing `make_animal`, if/when I do think of something I'll be sure to write a complete answer.

Comment: @DutChen18 Without a base class, `make_noise()` should be a template function to handle different types, eg: `template<typename T> void make_noise(const T& target) { std::cout << target.get_noise() << std::endl; }` Now you can pass in any object that has a `get_noise()` method, whether it is polymorphic or not. No need for the `animal` struct at all, especially one with *two* pointers in it instead of just *one* pointer as in the original code. So, you've actually *doubled* your array size by using that struct.

Comment: @RemyLebeau A generic `make_noise` wouldn't work when the type is not known at compile time. Also, the array is `std::vector<cat>` not `std::vector<animal>` so it does *not* contain two pointers, `sizeof(cat)` is a single byte.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau excellent point. A thought I had: when you create a vec of cats, you discard the utility of the base class anyway. On my x86_64 linux machine with gcc, the bare struct with no members and no base class consumes 1 byte, but a pointer to the same object consumes 8. I believe squeezing lower memory usage out of c++ classes is this instance is much less useful than switching to a paradigm that ditches classes and inheritance all together. Still interesting, but in a world where Python runs in production it's probably not worth while.

Comment: @DutChen18 if you forgo the use of a base class, then the object type *would* be known at compile-time, especially in the case of `vector<cat>`, etc

Comment: Apologies. I misread the question.

Comment: "storing 10 billion kittens would require 80 gigabytes of memory" - memory is cheap. If you really need that many kittens in memory at once, then just buy a machine with (say) 128G of memory - problem solved (and probably cheaper than paying the engineers needed to squeeze the memory requirements down to something smaller).

Comment: Maybe not relevant here or maybe it is; if you mark leaf classes `final` and compile with LTO, then the compiler can often work wonders with regard to devirtualizing things etc.

Comment: How is storing an explicit pointer in your class better than letting the compiler put a hidden one there for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because of the vtable pointer, the cat class is 8 bytes in size and storing 10 billion kittens would require 80 gigabytes of memory.
> ...
> So finally, for my question, is there a better way? I don't mind writing some boilerplate template metaprogramming magic if that helps keep the rest of my code clean.

If storing object type inside each object is not practical, another way is to store the object type in the pointer.

In 64-bit address space, you can allocate your objects of different types in such a way, that a plain pointer encodes the object type naturally.

Say, you'd like to handle up to 16Mi of 256-byte cats and up to 8Mi of 512-byte dogs - 4GiB pool per object type. You *reserve* one 8GiB region of virtual address space with `mmap`, and allocate cats from the first half of the region, dogs - from the second. Due to demand paging, page frames (physical RAM) are allocated only for pages of the region which were stored into.

A pointer to an object is a sum of region's base address and an offset. With 4GiB (2³²) object pools, the high 32 bits of the 64-bit offset naturally encode the object type, `0` for cats and `1` for dogs.

The non-polymorphic base class has to implement run-time polymorphism of each otherwise virtual function.

Here is a working sketch:

```
#include <memory>
#include <new>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/interprocess/anonymous_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>

// Compile-time map of class types to integer.
template<class T> using Type = std::common_type<T>;
template<class T> void type_to_pool_id(Type<T>); // Use ADL to find type_to_pool_id declarations in namespaces of T.

template<uintptr_t N_POOLS, uintptr_t POOL_SIZE>
struct PoolAllocator {
    struct Pool {
        struct Free { Free* prev; };
        Free* free = 0; // A stack of deallocated elements.
        size_t allocated = 0;

        Pool() noexcept = default;
        Pool(Pool const&) = delete;
        Pool& operator=(Pool const&) = delete;

        void deallocate(void* p) noexcept {
            free = new (p) Free{free}; // Stack push.
        }

        void* allocate(size_t size, uintptr_t pool) {
            if(free)
                return std::exchange(free, free->prev); // Stack pop.
            auto allocated2 = allocated + std::max(size, sizeof(Free));
            if(allocated2 > POOL_SIZE)
                throw std::bad_alloc();
            return reinterpret_cast<void*>(pool + std::exchange(allocated, allocated2));
        }
    };

    boost::interprocess::mapped_region reserved_region_{boost::interprocess::anonymous_shared_memory(N_POOLS * POOL_SIZE)};
    Pool pools_[N_POOLS];

    uintptr_t get_pool_id(void* p) const noexcept {
        auto offset = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(p) - reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(reserved_region_.get_address());
        return offset / POOL_SIZE;
    }

    void deallocate(uintptr_t pool_id, void* p) noexcept {
        pools_[pool_id].deallocate(p);
    }

    void* allocate(uintptr_t pool_id, size_t size) {
        return pools_[pool_id].allocate(size, reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(reserved_region_.get_address()) + POOL_SIZE * pool_id);
    }

    template<class T>
    void destroy(T& t) noexcept(noexcept(t.~T())) {
        void* p = &t;
        t.~T();
        deallocate(get_pool_id(p), p);
    }

    template<class T, class... Args>
    T* create(Args&&... args) {
        constexpr auto pool_id = decltype(type_to_pool_id(Type<T>{}))::value; // Use ADL to find type_to_pool_id declarations in namespaces of T.
        void* p = allocate(pool_id, sizeof(T));
        try {
            return new (p) T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
        }
        catch(...) {
            deallocate(pool_id, p); // Don't leak memory should T constructor throw.
            throw;
        }
    }
};

// Non-polymorphic base class.
struct Animal {
    void destroy(); // Implements polymorphic behaviour.

    std::string get_noise(); // Implements polymorphic behaviour.

    template<class R, class F>
    R visit(F&& f); // Downcast to the derived class.

    using Pool = PoolAllocator<2, uintptr_t{1} << 32>;
    static Pool* pool; // All derived objects are allocated from this pool.

protected:
    ~Animal() noexcept = default; // Non-polymorphic, destroy must be used instead.
};
Animal::Pool* Animal::pool = 0;

void Animal::destroy() { // Implements polymorphic behaviour.
    visit<void>([](auto& derived) { pool->destroy(derived); });
}

std::string Animal::get_noise() { // Implements polymorphic behaviour.
    return visit<std::string>([](auto& derived) { return derived.get_noise(); });
}

// unique_ptr support.
struct AnimalDeleter {
    void operator()(Animal* a) const {
        if(a)
            a->destroy();
    }
};
template<class T>
using AnimalPtr = std::unique_ptr<T, AnimalDeleter>;

// Derived classes.
struct Cat : Animal {
    std::string get_noise() { return "Meow"; }
    ~Cat() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
};
struct Dog : Animal {
    std::string get_noise() { return "Woof"; }
    ~Dog() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
};

// Compile-time map of class types to integer.
std::integral_constant<int, 0> type_to_pool_id(Type<Cat>);
std::integral_constant<int, 1> type_to_pool_id(Type<Dog>);

// Downcast to the derived class. Requires all derived class definitions to be available at this point.
template<class R, class F>
R Animal::visit(F&& f) {
    switch(pool->get_pool_id(this)) {
    case decltype(type_to_pool_id(Type<Cat>{}))::value: return f(static_cast<Cat&>(*this));
    case decltype(type_to_pool_id(Type<Dog>{}))::value: return f(static_cast<Dog&>(*this));
    default: throw;
    }
}

int main() {
    // Setup the pool in main.
    Animal::Pool pool;
    Animal::pool = &pool;

    AnimalPtr<Cat> cat(pool.create<Cat>());
    std::cout << cat->get_noise() << '\n';
    AnimalPtr<Animal> base_cat = move(cat);
    std::cout << base_cat->get_noise() << '\n';

    AnimalPtr<Dog> dog(pool.create<Dog>());
    std::cout << dog->get_noise() << '\n';
    AnimalPtr<Animal> base_dog = move(dog);
    std::cout << base_dog->get_noise() << '\n';
}
```

Outputs:

```
Meow
Meow
Woof
Woof
Dog::~Dog()
Cat::~Cat()
```

[Better Code: Runtime Polymorphism - Sean Parent](https://youtu.be/QGcVXgEVMJg) explains the ideas in greater detail.

Comment: Wow! storing using the pointer itself to identity the dynamic type is a very neat trick, and using visitors + generic lambdas avoids the need have a look up table for every virtual function. This also gave me the idea to use alignment and the low order bits of the pointer to determine an object's dynamic type. I have some more things I want to try but I'll accept this answer for now. Thank you for the amazing insight!

Comment: @DutChen18 Yes, unused unset lower bits and the top 16 bits of 64-bit pointers are often used to store additional information. The benefit of this method is that a plain pointer remains a plain valid pointer with its original bit representation while also encoding the type information.

Comment: The maximum region size I was able to reserve is 2⁴⁶ bytes, on my Linux workstation with CPU supporting 48-bit virtual and physical addresses in 64-bit mode.